# Define datatype in Python

Tags: python, logic

I have some inkling of how this might work, but I do not know the exact syntax of how to do it.

An example:

```
def function(string):
    string = string + "A"
```

How will the function know that what I am inputting is a string?
Is it something along the lines of...

```
string = type.str
```

Comment: It won't.  The operation `string + "A"` will succeed if it can, otherwise it won't.  (`string` doesn't have to be a string for it to succeed.)  It's not clear what you're asking here.  Why do you want the function to "know" that what you're passing in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to check the type of a variable. First, you could check if the parameter is an instance of `str`:

```
def isstring(parameter):
    return isinstance(parameter, str)
```

Another way could be to try to concatenate a string (in this case `""`) with the parameter and catch eventually exceptions (`TypeError` exception):

```
def isstring(parameter):
    try:
        parameter += ""
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

Another way could be to use `type` (similar to `isinstance`, but difference mostly when polymorphism is involved):

```
def isstr(parameter):
    return type(parameter) == str
```

You could also use `assert`, but if you want just to check if a parameter is of a certain type, I would adopt the first case.

Comment: You shouldn't check for types like this; it's incredibly unpythonic.  If you *must*, you should check against `basestring`, not `str`

Comment: @sapi unpythonic, or however you want to define what I am showing, answers the OP's question. If these constructs exist, it's for a reason, I believe.

Comment: @sapi In this case, checking against `str` is perfectly fine, or am I wrong?

Comment: The isinstance check should use basestring, or it will fail for unicode. The type one would need to check both.

Comment: @sapi Would this happen also for Python 3?

Comment: Nah, it should be fine in Python 3; it won't match bytes, but in most cases that's expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

No, you could NOT, python is dynamic but not static, so it could not know the argument type at "compile time", instead, you could check the input type by assert.

```
def fun(string):
    assert isinstance(string, basestring)  # we usually check if it type is basestring as this works fine for both ASCII string and Unicode.
    string = string + "A"
    return string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun(2)
```